# django global variable across web pages?

Tags: django, request

How to pass a variable between web pages/functions?

For example, let's say when I visit webpage "test3.html", I'd like to get the sum of variables a_test1 and a_test2, which are "global" variables which increased as visiting test1.html and test2.html. test1.html, test2.html and test3.html could be visited multiple times and independently. The following code doesn't work as it is, but it would if I can somehow make a_test1 and a_test2 global variables? Can that be done?

Another option maybe passing these variables by the "request" parameter? Can it be done that way?

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^test1/$', views.test1),
    url(r'^test2/$', views.test2),
    url(r'^test3/$', views.test3),
]
```

in views.py:

```
def test1(request):
    a_test1=1+a_test1
    return render(request,'test1.html',{'a_test1': a_test1})
    #other stuffs

def test2(request):
    a_test2=1+a_test2
    return render(request,'test2.html',{'a_test2': a_test2})
    #other stuffs

def test3(request):
    a_test3=a_test1+a_test2
    return render(request,'test3.html',{'a_test3': a_test3})
    #other stuffs
```

Comment: I have not needed to do this but you can try creating a new class to do this. put the variable in the class, increment every time you load a page.

Comment: A global variable would be the same for every user. Is your system going to be used by only one person?

Comment: Hmmm, looks like it has to be a "global" variable for a particular session only. Can that be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use session variables in order to share variables across multiple templates and views! for example:

```
def test1(request):
    a_test1=1+a_test1  
    request.session['my_variable'] = a_test1
    return render(request,'test1.html',{'a_test1': a_test1})
```

With that you can access request.session['my_variable'] everywhere on your site!

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/

Comment: This is absolutely the right approach, except it's `request.session` not the other way around.

Comment: This is great. Exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks a lot!